# google maps saving geocoded point infringement

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know that saving the geocoded lat,lng in a DB (or other media) , 
is against the Terms Of Use, but what if i "take" that point (of course while displaying it on the map) and instead of saving that `lat,lng` in the DB , i save:

```
lat + C , lng + C
```

where C is some const.

Later when i query from the DB , i query lat - C , lng -C.

Is this legal ? currently i don't have the $10k needed and i do want to use their geocoder.

Thanks

Comment: Please tell me what this has to do with programming?

Comment: It is, because many developers who use google maps api , like myself, are looking for solutions and not always aware to the terms of use. 
I've SO before for this kind of question with out of luck.

Comment: To understand why, you should probably read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When you steal a wallet and put a own dollar into it, is it legal then?**

However: it's not  illegal to store the latLng's somewhere as long as you store them there to use them later **only** inside a Maps-API-application.

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=en#geocoder_exists

Comment: Of course i'm not trying to steal anything. Just find out what solutions are there, for small scale usage. If any.

And i was mistaken to think, that if i have a process that does backend actions on lat,lng saved for caching, i'll be unable to run it due to Terms Of use, unless they'll be displayed on map at the same time. From your statement and link, i see it possible as long as i'll use the google maps api.

Good. Thanks a lot.